# Selecting rows first by Id then by datetime - with or without a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, database-performance

I need to create statistics from several log tables. Most of the time every hour  but sometimes more frequently every 5 minutes.

Selecting rows only by `datetime` isn't fast enough for larger logs so I thought I select only rows that are new since the last query by storing the max `Id` and reusing it next time:

```
SELECT TOP(1000) * -- so that it's not too much
FROM [dbo].[Log]
WHERE Id > lastId AND [Timestamp] >= timestampMin
ORDER BY [Id] DESC
```

[image: select1]

My question: is the SQL Server smart enough to:

- first filter the rows by `Id` and then by the `Timestamp` even if I change the order of the conditions or does the condition order matter or
- do I need a subquery to first select the rows by `Id` and then filter them by the `Timestamp`.

with subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM [dbo].[Log]
    WHERE Id > lastId
    ORDER BY [Id] DESC
) t
WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= timestampMin
```

[image: select2]

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    -- other columns    
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I tried to use the query plan to find out how it works but it turns out that I cannot read it and I don't understand it.

Comment: The order of conditions doesn't matter, the engine sorts out the best way to use them. Your subquery is returning a different result then the original due to your `TOP 1000` inside there. Is that what you want? I think the `TOP 1000` should be in the outer query.

Comment: Most of the time, if you ask: "is SQL Server smart enough..." the answer will usually be yes.

Comment: @NickyvV now that you mention the `TOP 1000` I think you're right. If I put it in the inner query the result could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't have an index on `TimeStamp` so SQL Server will always use the Clustered Index (`Id`) first (the Clustered index seek you see in the query plan) to find the first row matching `Id > lastId` and *then* perform a scan on the remaining rows with the predicate `[Timestamp] >= timestampMin` (actually is the other way around since you are sorting in reverse order with `DESC`).

If you were to add a index on `TimeStamp` SQL Server *might* use it based on:

1. the cardinality of the predicate `[Timestamp] >= timestampMin`. Please note that cardinality is always an estimate based on statistics (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx) and the cardinality estimator (it changed from SQL 2012 to 2014+, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600374.aspx).
2. how covering the non-clustered index is (since you are using the wildcard it would hardly matters anyway). If the non-clustered index is non covering SQL Server would have to add a `Key Lookup` (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326635(v=sql.105).aspx) operator in order to retrieve all the fields (or perform a join). This will likely make the index not worthwhile for this query.

Also note that your two queries - the one with subplan and the one without - are functionally different. The first will give you the first 1000 rows the have **both** `Id > lastId AND [Timestamp] >= timestampMin`. The second will give you only the rows having `[Timestamp] >= timestampMin` from the first 1000 rows having `Id > lastId`. So, for example, you might get 1000 rows from the first query but less than that on the second one.